# Simplify Algorithm graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

The below are 3 algorithms for the same problem. How can one find the fastest algorithm?

[image: enter link description here]

I tried to divide both gradients by log and square root to find the steepest graph.

Comment: What do **you** think?

Comment: This lacks basic information needed to answer the question…

Comment: Divide both gradients by log and square root to find the steepest graph?

Comment: @rikket Good. add this to your question, and explain why it didn't give you the right answer, or where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure what to do. I will try it out tomorrow and post results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am more comftorable giving guidelines after your comment - it proves you showed some effort.

You basically want to get to a formula `t = f(n)`, and chose the one that grows slowest.

It can be done by using the information you have with some basic algebra, I will give an example for the rightest graph, and you will need to do the same for the others and get their function.

Rightest graph:

We know that for each increase of 1 in 2^n, there is increase of 4 in 2^t. From this:

```
2^t/2^n = 4 --> 2^t = 4*2^n --(log)--> log(2^t) = log(4*2^n) --> 
--> t = log(4) + log(2^n) --> t = 2 + n
```

Use the same technique for the rest, and chose the one that is growing slowest, and you got your answer.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was not sure what to do. I will try it out tomorrow and post results